# Как исправить "MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '???N_.???' in 'field list'" с использованием "hibernate" and "springframwork"?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Моё java-приложение работает с БД под SQL. После добавления в БД новой таблицы “paragraph_type” и новой связанной колонки “PARTYPE_ID” в таблицу “paragraphs” появились ошибки:

- [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] -

  [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils $ LoggingErrorHandler] -

Локальная СУБД mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2.
ДЛя взаимодействия с ней используется springframework и hibernate.

Эти топики мне не помогли:

- Q: [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException - Unknown column in field list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351939/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-in-fi?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C193.1447);
- Q: [Hibernate: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241266/hibernate-com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-co?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C177.5856);
- Q: [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column in 'field list' using Criteria and mapping annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534601/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-in-fi?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C139.3616);
- Q: [I keep getting the error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '. . . . ' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127955/i-keep-getting-the-error-com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexcept?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C139.3440);
- Q: [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '' in 'field list' Using spring boot and JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733514/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-in?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C139.1860);
- Q: [MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column ' ____ ' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507940/mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-in-field-list?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C352.4885);
- Q: [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '____' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141472/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C256.1279);
- Q: [Hibernate : MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column ' ____ ' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871118/hibernate-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-in-field-list?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C202.4306);
- и т.д.

Структура новой таблицы "paragraph_type":

```
CREATE TABLE `paragraph_type` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PARTYPE` char(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Структура таблицы "paragraphs":

```
CREATE TABLE `paragraphs` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PARTYPE_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, //NEW
  `PID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `CONTENT` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOCUMENT_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `APPENDIX` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `APPENDIX_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `DOCUMENT_ID` (`DOCUMENT_ID`),
  KEY `pid_key` (`PID`),
  KEY `p_type_key` (`PARTYPE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `p_type_key` FOREIGN KEY (`PARTYPE_ID`) REFERENCES `paragraph_type` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `paragraphs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PID`) REFERENCES `paragraphs` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18823 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Класс **"Paragraph.java"**:

```
...
@Entity
...
@Table(name = "paragraphs")
public class Paragraph implements INodeEntity, Comparable {
    ...
    private long id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull(message = "802")
    private ParagraphsType paragraphsType;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARTYPE_ID")
    public ParagraphsType getParagraphsType(){
        return paragraphsType;
    }
    public void setParagraphsType(ParagraphsType paragraphsType){
        this.paragraphsType = paragraphsType;
    }
    ...
    @NotNull(message = "802")
    private NormativeDocument normativeDocument;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID")
    public NormativeDocument getNormativeDocument() {
        return normativeDocument;
    }
    public void setNormativeDocument(NormativeDocument normativeDocument) {
        this.normativeDocument = normativeDocument;
    }
    ....
}
```

Класс **"ParagraphsType.java"**:

```
....
@Entity
@Table(name = "paragraph_type")
public class ParagraphsType implements IEntity {

    private long id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private char[] paragraphsType = new char[3];
    @Column(name = "PARTYPE_ID")
    public char[] getParagraphsType() {
        return paragraphsType;
    }
    public void setParagraphsType(char[] paragraphsType) {
        this.paragraphsType = paragraphsType;
    }
    ...
}
```

xml-файл: **"pr.xml"**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="providersRepository" class="ru.leasoft.armspk.ProvidersRepository" factory-method="get"
      lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" init-method="initDatasourceMap">
      ...
    <property name="paragraphs" ref="paragraphsDao"/>
    <property name="paragraphType" ref="paragraphTypeDao"/>
      ...
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Класс провайдера для таблицы "paragraphs" **"ParagraphsProvider.java"**:

```
@Repository("paragraphsDao")
public class ParagraphsProvider implements Paragraphs {
    ...
    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Paragraph> getAll() {
        ...
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported operation: getAll()");
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Paragraph getById(long id) {
        Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Paragraph.class, id);
        if (paragraph == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("3");
        }
        ...
        return paragraph;
    }
    ...
}
```

Класс провайдера для таблицы "paragraph_type" **"ParagraphsTypesProvider.java"**:

```
@Repository("paragraphTypeDao")
public class ParagraphsTypesProvider implements CRUDDatasource<ParagraphsType>, FilteringProvider<ParagraphsType> {

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Resource(name = "permissionChecker")
    private PermissionChecker permissionChecker;

    private FilterPaginator filterPaginator = new FilterPaginator(ParagraphsType.class);
    @Override
    public FilteredResult filterAll(Filter filter) {
        return filterPaginator.doFiltration(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), filter);
    }
    ...
}
```

Лог об ошибках при выполнении:

```
WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22>
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Unknown column 'paragraphs4_.PARTYPE_ID' in 'field list'>
ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] - <Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.>
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'paragraphs4_.PARTYPE_ID' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...
WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22>
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Unknown column 'paragraphs0_.PARTYPE_ID' in 'field list'>
WARN [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts] - <HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@4bb96906<rs=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet@4a1a93e8>>
WARN [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] - <HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries>
ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] - <Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.>
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'paragraphs0_.PARTYPE_ID' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Как избежать этого исключения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в DDL таблицы `paragraph_type` описаны колонки `ID` и `PARTYPE`. А в классе, на который мапится табличка описаны `@Column(name = "ID")` и `@Column(name = "PARTYPE_ID")`. Отсюда и ошибка. Сделайте в классе `ParagraphsType` `@Column(name = "PARTYPE")` и думаю будет Вам счастье.